# Disable spring security for subdomain

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have an application which can be accessed via different domains of type

> www.*.example.com

For ex-

[www.test.example.com](http://www.test.example.com)

[www.npc.example.com](http://www.npc.example.com)

[www.train.example.com](http://www.train.example.com)

When configuring the spring security (authentication/oauth) , I'd like to enable security only for certain subdomains and keep it disabled for others.

Say enable it for only "www.test.example.com"

Here's my filter config -

```
@Bean
    fun securityWebFilterChain(
        http: ServerHttpSecurity
    ): SecurityWebFilterChain {
         return http.csrf().disable()
            .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
            .and()
            .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/**")
               .authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic().and().oauth2Login { oauth2 ->
                        oauth2.authenticationSuccessHandler(oauthSuccessHandler)
                            .authorizedClientService(redisOauthClientService)
                    }
            .build()
    }
```

The base url is present as another header. Is there a  way to use the header to enable/disable security config? Any other approach would also be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `ServerWebExchangeMatcher` implementation that checks if the request comes from a subdomain and use it in your DSL, something like:

```java
http
    .authorizeExchange()
        .matcher(new MySubdomainMatcher()).permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/**").authenticated();

class MySubdomainMatcher implements ServerWebExchangeMatcher {

    public Mono<MatchResult> matches(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        // perform the logic in the request
    }

}
```